# Performance of containers inside loops

Tags: c++, performance

Do I have to care about code like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < BIG; ++i) {
  std::vector<int> v (10);
  ... do something with v ...
}
```

refactoring as:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i=0; i < BIG; ++i) {
  v.clear(); v.resize(10); // or fill with zeros
  ... do something with v ...
}
```

or the compiler is smart enough to optimize memory (de)allocation?

I prefer the first one, since the `std::vector<int> v` is out of scope when I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Go with the first. If it later turns out to measurably affect performance, it's easy to change.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the first is causing a tangible slow down? If that's the only allocation in the loop body, you're probably going to hit the fast path of the allocator each loop iteration (which is frequently <100 cycles) and always get the same chunk of memory, which will be already in cache.

Comment: I would suggest to almost always use former version or for size of 10, I may use `std::array` or `int v[10]`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: mine is a theoretical question. I am trying to understand if after compiler optimization and compilation the two codes are likely to produce the same program or if in principle the second version can save some allocation/deallocation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice it is difficult for a compiler to generate identical code for the two, unless the author of the standard library gives it some help.

In particular, `vector` is typically implemented vaguely like this:

```
template <class T, class Allocator=std::allocator<T>>
class vector {
    T *data;
    size_t allocated_size, current_size;
public:
    vector(size_t);
    // ...
};
```

I'm simplifying a lot, but that's enough to demonstrate the main point I'm trying to make here: the vector object itself does *not* contain the actual data. The vector object only contains a pointer to the data along with some metadata about allocation size and such.

That means each time you create a `vector` of 10 ints, `vector`'s constructor has to use `operator new` to allocate space for (at least) 10 ints (well, technically, it uses the Allocator type that's passed to it to do that, but by default, that'll use the free store). Likewise, when it goes out of scope, it uses the allocator (again, defaulting to the free store) to destroy the 10 ints.

One obvious way to avoid that allocation would be to allocate space for at least a small number of elements inside the vector object itself, and only allocate space on the free store when/if the data grew larger than that space allowed. That way, creating your vector of 10 ints would be equivalent to just creating an array of 10 ints (either native array or `std::array`)--on a typical machine, it would be allocated on the stack when execution enters the enclosing function, and all that would happen on entry to the block would be initializing the contents (if you try to read some of it before writing to it).

At least in the general case, we can't do that though. For example, if I move assign a vector, that move assignment can't throw an exception--even if move assignment of the individual elements *would* throw an exception. As such, it *can't* do any operations on the individual elements. With a structure like above, that requirement is easy to meet--we basically do a shallow copy from the source to the destination, and zero out all the items in the source.

There is, however, a container in the standard library that *does* allow that optimization: `std::basic_string` specifically allows it. It might initially look a bit strange (and honestly, it *is* a bit strange), but if you replaced you `std::vector` with a `std::basic_string<int> v(10, 0);`, and used it on an implementation that includes the short-string optimization (e.g., VC++) you might get a substantial improvement in speed. One of the ways `std::string` is able to allow this is that you can't use it to store types that throw exceptions though--if `int` is just an example, and you might really need to store other types that can throw, then `basic_string` probably won't work for you. Even for native types like `int`, `char_traits<T>` may be an incomplete type, so this may not work anyway. If you decide you need to badly enough, you can use it as a container for your own types, by 1) ensuring they don't throw, and 2) specializing char_traits for your type. Bottom line: it can be interesting to experiment with this, but it's rarely (if ever) practical, and almost impossible to recommend.

The obvious alternative would be to use an `std::array<int, 10>` instead. If the size of the array is fixed, this is probably the preferred choice. Unlike instantiating `basic_string` over a non-character type, you'd be using this as intended, and getting its intended behavior. The weakness is that the size is a compile-time constant, so if you might ever need to change size at run-time, it's not an option at all.

Comment: You can't do an SSO-like optimization on vectors. Their `swap()` isn't allowed to invalidate iterators. Also, vector move assignment isn't noexcept and may throw if the allocators compare unequal and doesn't propagate on move assignment.

Comment: No, when you swap, the iterators still have to refer to the same object as before (i.e., if you swap `{1, 2}` and `{3, 4}`, an iterator pointing to `1` still has to point to `1`). A "fat" iterator doesn't help there. Also, using a `basic_string<T>` as a container is a bad idea; for all except the four character types, `char_traits<T>` can be an incomplete type.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the comments--I've done some editing to reflect them (and, particularly, thanks for pointing out the problem with `swap` with an SSO-like vector, which I hadn't previously considered).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I perfectly understand your answer. What about the non-dynamic allocated memory? For example what about `T* data` (the pointer itself)? Is it allocated in the stack 1 time or `BIG` times in the first case? I know it won't make any practical difference.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra: At least with the compilers of which I'm aware, all the stack space used by a function is allocated at once when the function is entered.